# Hibernate is not inserting data to DB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a simple hibernate project that should insert and select a record from the db.
I setup a Bean, DAO Interface and implemented it in DAOImple class.

However, it doesn't insert the data to the table.
The main print a new id, but still no record is created in the table.

This is the code I have :

Program.java

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfigurations.class);
        
        ProductDAO dao = context.getBean(ProductDAO.class);
        
        System.out.println("Creating product");
        dao.create(new Product("Chocklate", 17.9f));
        System.out.println("Product created successfully");
        
        
        System.out.println("***********************");
        for(Product p : dao.findAll())
        {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
```

SpringConfiguration.java

```
import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("mypackage")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SpringConfigurations {

    /*@Autowired
    Environment env;*/
    
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean("hibernateTemplate") 
    HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate()
    {
        HibernateTemplate template = new HibernateTemplate(getSessionFactoryBean().getObject());
        template.setCheckWriteOperations(false);                
        return template;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactoryBean()
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource( getDataSource());        
        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("mypackage");
        
        return factoryBean;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager()
    {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactoryBean().getObject());
        
        return transactionManager;
    }
    
    public DriverManagerDataSource getDataSource()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(getHibernateProperties().getProperty("connectionString"));
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    public Properties getHibernateProperties()
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect");
        props.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        props.put("hibernate.connection.autocommit", true);
        props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        props.put("connectionString","jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=myDB;integratedSecurity=true");
        return props;
    }
}
```

Product.java (Bean)

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Product {
    private int id;
    
    private String name;
    
    private float price;

    public Product() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Product( String name, float price) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    public Product(int id, String name, float price) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id") //in case the field is same name as the variable, no need to mention the name="id"
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name="price")
    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", price=" + price + "]";
    }
}
```

ProductDAOImpl.java

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component

public class ProductDAOImpl implements ProductDAO {

    @Autowired
    HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
        
    @Transactional
    public void create(Product product) {
        Integer ret = (Integer) hibernateTemplate.save(product);
        System.out.println(ret);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void update(Product product) {
        hibernateTemplate.update(product);
    }
    
    @Transactional
    public void delete(Product product) {
        hibernateTemplate.delete(product);
    }

    public Product find(int id) {
        return hibernateTemplate.get(Product.class,id);
    }

    public List<Product> findAll() {
        return hibernateTemplate.loadAll(Product.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Add `@EnableTransactionManagement` to your `@Configuration`. Pro-tip, don't use `HibernateTemplate` use the `SessionFactory` directly to get the current session and use the `Session` to work with your entities. The usage of `HibernateTemplate` has been discouraged since the release of Hibernate 3.0.1!

Comment: Thanks a-lot. It helped. Also thanks for the Tip, well noted